# How to find distance from point to axis at specific angle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I want to find the distance between a point and an x or y axis, but at a certain angle. Hopefully the diagram below will be able to better explain what I am looking for.

I am trying to find the distance of the *red* and *blue* lines, the distance between point $p$ and the x-axis, and point $p$ and y-axis respectfully.

The lines originate from an arbitrary point $p$ and are angled by an arbitrary angle $\theta$ and $\theta+90^\circ$

[image]

Comment: do you know trigonometry?

Comment: Can we assume that x, y of P are given. How P is given?

Comment: You need to use Patagonian equations

Comment: You need to be sure of sign of coordinate and sign of angle (conventionally CCW is taken positive) . Inclined length by trig is more in magnitude. $L_x = |x|/\cos \theta ,\, L_y = |y|/\cos \theta $

Answer (score 0):

This is not difficult, the distance to axis $y$ will be $\large{\frac{|x|}{\sin \theta}}$, the distance to axis $x$ will be $\large{\frac{|y|}{\sin \theta}}$. Just draw lines parallel to axes and consider right triangles that will be formed by constructed lines, axes and your red and blue lines.